# Yahoo! Pipes: getting "count" results in "output"

Tags: yahoo-pipes

Is there a way to extract the results from "count" operator in the final output on Yahoo! Pipes? For example, I am looking at the number of postings on my RSS news feed. I just want to know how many postings were there. So far I have been unable to retrieve the frequency number in the "Pipe Output." Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The JSON result of your pipe includes a "count" property with the number of items returned. (Click "Get as JSON" on the pipe's page)

e.g. [JSON output](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=cbfa29ca85350f652d83f655178c0558&_render=json) for a pipe.

You could also make a [pipe to just return the count](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=424412e51a611fcb31934228189c9fe9) of an RSS feed.